# How to get the frequency of a term in a document using lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to find the occurrence of certain words in a document. For example, I want to find out how many times the words `{horror, crime, mystery, comedy, action}` show up in a document of approximately 10,000 words.

Is it possible to do this with lucene?  Or can I not specify the terms I want a count of with Lucene?

Comment: I put a code-like specification in a code block and removed the redundant conclusion at the end.